# Filter duplicate results in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a patients table and patient_histories table, I want to write the sql query which returns the total number of new patients who have visited (marked by patient_histories table) the hospital only one time from the beginning date to search date.

#### Current records

patients table

```
|id |name   |
|---|----   |
|24 |Pranish|
|25 |Manish |
|26 |Jeny   |
|27 |John   |
|---|----   |
```

patient_histories table

```
| id   |  patient_id   |  year  | month | day |
|------|:------------: |  -----:|------:| ---:|
| 1    | 24            |  2019  | 04    |  01 |
| 2    | 25            |  2019  | 04    |  01 |
| 3    | 25            |  2019  | 08    |  19 |
| 4    | 26            |  2019  | 08    |  19 |
| 5    | 27            |  2019  | 08    |  20 |
|------|:------------: |  -----:|------:| ---:|
```

#### Expected result

**search criteria**

should have only one history count for given date (2019/08/19)

```
| id   |  patient_id   |  year  | month | day |
|------|:------------: |  -----:|------:| ---:|
| 4    | 26            |  2019  | 08    |  19 |
|------|:------------: |  -----:|------:| ---:|
```

should have two history count for given date (2019/04/01)

```
| id   |  patient_id   |  year  | month | day |
|------|:------------: |  -----:|------:| ---:|
| 1    | 24            |  2019  | 04    |  01 |
| 2    | 25            |  2019  | 04    |  01 |
|------|:------------: |  -----:|------:| ---:|
```

#### Current result

```
select distinct
    patients.id as id,
    patient_histories.year as year,
    patient_histories.month as month,
    patient_histories.day as day
from patients
    join patient_histories
    on patients.id=patient_histories.patient_id
where patients.gender="female"
    and patient_histories.year="2019"
group by
    patients.id,
    patient_histories.year,
    patient_histories.month,
    patient_histories.day
having count(patient_histories.patient_id) = 1
```

```
|id | year  | month | day |
|-- | ----- | ----- | ----|
|24 | 2019  | 4     | 1   |
|25 | 2019  | 4     | 1   |
|25 | 2019  | 8     | 19  |
|26 | 2019  | 8     | 19  |
|27 | 2019  | 8     | 20  |
```

Comment: No duplicate recodes in your result, if you think row 3 and row 4 is duplicate please remove `patients.id` after `group by`.

Comment: Store dates as dates.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this can be done in a single select, but you can create a temporary table that is a copy of patients_histories and then delete all entries from it that contain visits of patients that already have visited your hospital. After that you can select from your temporary table grouping by the date and counting the entries.

Here is a fiddle for you: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rT8kHPmBZJSLxdTSk5HQid/0

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rank on history table to choose first added row by id. Oracle example:

```
select distinct
    patients.id as id,
    patient_histories.year as year,
    patient_histories.month as month,
    patient_histories.day as day
from patients
    join (select 
        patient_histories.patient_id,
        patient_histories.year,
        patient_histories.month,
        patient_histories.day,
        rank() over(partition by patient_histories.patient_id order by 
            patient_histories.year,
            patient_histories.month,
            patient_histories.day) rnk from patient_histories) patient_histories
    on patients.id=patient_histories.patient_id and rnk=1
where patients.gender="female"
    and patient_histories.year="2019"
group by
    patients.id,
    patient_histories.year,
    patient_histories.month,
    patient_histories.day
```

Result:

```
|id | year  | month | day |
|-- | ----- | ----- | ----|
|24 | 2019  | 4     | 1   |
|25 | 2019  | 4     | 1   |
|26 | 2019  | 8     | 19  |
|27 | 2019  | 8     | 20  |
```

MySQL example link https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51kQBJiCnETDqS2uyGWUsP/0